# Battery Voltage Monitoring

Tags: mosfet, voltage-divider, battery-operated

I have designed a simple battery voltage monitoring circuit to monitor a 3.7V Li-Po battery. My microcontroller (ESP32) uses a 3.3V supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3oBVZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The MOSFET M1 is an attempt to save power when I'm not measuring the battery level.

Is this circuit suitable to measure voltage across the ADC pin of my MCU? Please review the circuit and provide me with inputs if I'm doing something wrong, or if it could improved in any way.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of the MOSFET? All you need is a voltage divider to ensure you are below the ADC ref, and perhaps a current-limiting resistor.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the purpose of this circuit is. It looks like R2, R3 are a voltage divider and you want to use M1 to connect/disconnect this voltage divider to save battery while not monitoring. M1 is an NMOS that means that in order to fully close M1 the voltage at MCU_DOUT needs to be **higher** than the battery voltage. When MCU_DOUT = Vbat then this will behave as a source follower meaning you will get Vbat - Vgs(M1) at the resistor divider. Consider using a PMOS instead! You should do more research and see what is generally done as you're not the first to want this.

Comment: Why do you have a MOSFET there? And what is MCU DOUT doing? You don't need any of that. And I thought you were measuring battery voltage? But your question implies measuring across the ADC pin? Which one is it?

Comment: I think the OP has the mosfet in an attempt to stop R2 and R3 draining the battery when the measurement isn't being made.

Comment: Sorry about the rookie mistakes- with the circuit as well as the question. I have made an edit explaining the use of the MOSFET 'M1' for turning the battery monitoring on and off, saving power when off

Comment: So... you picked some ebay wifi module with a 160MHz CPU and then you are concerned about 330uA continuous current...? Meanwhile the wifi radio spits out what, 100mW power?

Comment: @Lundin Yes, because my MCU sleeps for about 23.5 hours a day(not continuously though)

Comment: Anyway, MOSFET are ideal for switching signals with high currents. But you don't need to draw any current just for measuring, so you could simply use an analog switch instead. Then Rds(on) becomes no issue either, in case you need high accuracy voltage measuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on your circuit is using a N channel mos, since the source is floating, it's difficult to predict when it gonna switch.

The design below, using a p channel mos solves this issue. Note the Mos has a low Vgsth that allows to switch with low voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f89y7a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you tell me what is the purpose of Q2 in your circuit?

Comment: Tie the gate down so M1 become conductive, you could do it directly from the MCU if it supports open drain pin and can handle the voltage.

Comment: Thanks for replying! It can handle the voltage but I dont know what you mean by "supports open drain pin".

Comment: Means it can either pull the pin down to GND or leave it floating. Google -> https://www.microcontrollertips.com/what-is-an-open-drain-faq/

Comment: Would it be possible to move the N-channel MOSFET to the midpoint of the divider and add a weak pull-down? Similar to what is described in this blog: https://jeelabs.org/2013/05/17/zero-powe-battery-measurement/

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have mentioned, the purpose of the MOSFET is not clear. I can only assume you want to turn it on and off each time you want to measure the battery voltage. First of all, you want to use a PMOSFET for this, rather than NMOSFET.

But, after saying that, it is not even needed. All you need is the battery voltage and a divider. You can still take the battery measurements at whatever intervals you want in your code, you don't need a MOSFET to do this. If you make sure your resistor values are quite high, then you can minimise current.

You may also consider using a buffer as well to feed the microcontroller pin to give a more stable reading to the MCU AIN pin:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvf7mk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using a buffer will stabilise your reading, so it won't get loaded down by anything, and change the reading. This will allow you to use higher value resistors in the divider, to further save power.

Comment: can you tell me why the buffer is needed?

Comment: I have added it in to the answer. It is not **needed**, but it will be useful to have

Comment: This opens up another can of worms called EMI though.

Comment: @Lundin should I be worried about the can of worms called EMI?

Comment: I have personally never had any issues with it when using this particular method, however, I admit I do not know enough about it to really include it in my answer. As I said though, I have used this circuit many times with no problems. I would not have thought for a simple battery monitoring circuit it would be much of an issue though?

Comment: @MCG Is the buffer "useful to have" in just this configuration in particular? Or is it always better to have when we use an ADC pin? Just curious

Comment: If the buffer is needed **depends on the ADC input of the MCU**. Some ADCs do not have a **high impedance input** but an input impedance of for example 10 kohm. Then the buffer is needed. If the ADC has a high input impedance, significantly higher than the impedance of the voltage divider, then the buffer is **not** needed. To improve EMI: add a capacitor in parallel with R2, a 100 nF capacitor will do the job.

Comment: I think @Bimpelrekkie has just explained it better than I would have done. I was only going to mention about input impedance. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: As a rule of thumb you don't use 1M resistors in radio applications. All of the board will soak up not only your own radiated power but external radio too. All wires, such as those to a battery, will act as antennas to some degree. A 100mW 2.4GHz signal leaking energy into the battery plane will cause that OP to dance.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for that info, I did not know that!

Comment: I would dispute the argument of not using 1MOhm resistors in radio applications. I have used up to 10MOhm resistors in multiple BT projects without any negative impact. In fact Nordic Semiconductors have a blog article on battery measurement, and they recommend high value resistors. https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/b/blog/posts/measuring-lithium-battery-voltage-with-nrf52

Comment: Using 1M resistor will also induce quite a bit of noise and the buffer will also draw current. All depends on the lifetime of the battery but if it's on the year range, power need to be cut from it. Lowest opamp are about 300nA + 1.85uA of the 2 1meg divider  and you are above 2uA. All depends on power requirements.

Comment: Using 1M resistors will be less than 2uA. That will last years on a Li-Po battery. A nano power or any low power op amp in a buffer configuration will draw tiny amounts of current. It will easily run for years on a Li-Po. Nothing I would ever be concerned about

Comment: You have to factor the rest of the board. Now commonly made RF beacon that should run 3-5 years on a coin cell battery

Comment: How can I factor the rest of the board when I don't know what is on there, or what it is doing? This is a low current solution that will add only a couple of uA with careful component selection.